# "Procedure too Large" Error

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Create_Mail_From_List_Exams()

Dim OutApp  As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim bodymessage  As String
Dim bodymessage1 As String
Dim bodymessage2 As String
Dim bodymessage3 As String
Dim bodymessage4  As String
Dim bodymessage5 As String
Dim Bodymessage6 As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error GoTo cleanup
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
For i = 3 To ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    bodymessage = ""
    bodymessage1 = ""
    bodymessage2 = ""
    bodymessage3 = ""
    bodymessage4 = ""
    bodymessage5 = ""
    ex6 = ""
    ex7 = ""
    ex8 = ""

    fr1 = ""
    fr2 = ""
    fr3 = ""
    fr4 = ""
    fr5 = ""
    fr6 = ""
    fr7 = ""
    fr8 = ""
    fr9 = ""

  'ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 12) = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 12) & "(" & cell.Row & "," & cell.Column & "), "

    If Sheets("Exams-email results").Cells(i, 3).Text Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
    LCase(Cells(i, "M").Value) = "dnm" Then

    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail

    .To = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Text



    .Subject = Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("T2") & " / " & Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("T5")


    '& "Groupe  " & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 10).Text & "  / Niveau " & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 11).Text'

    'A'

    If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("D3").Text = "Educ" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B7").Text
    End If


    If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("D3").Text = "A1" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B26").Text

    End If

      If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("D3").Text = "A2" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B27").Text

    End If

           If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("D3").Text = "A3" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B28").Text

    End If
        If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("D3").Text = "A4" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B29").Text

    End If
    If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("D3").Text = "A5" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B30").Text

    End If

         If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("D3").Text = "A6" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B31").Text

    End If

         If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("D3").Text = "A7" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B32").Text

    End If

         If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("D3").Text = "A8" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B33").Text

    End If

         'k'

         If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("D3").Text = "K1" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B20").Text

    End If

         If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("D3").Text = "K2" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B21").Text

    End If
            If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("D2").Text = "K3" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B22").Text

    End If


            If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("D3").Text = "K4" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B23").Text

    End If


            If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("D3").Text = "K5" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B24").Text

    End If



           'PS'




     If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("D3").Text = "PS1" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B35").Text
    End If




     If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("D3").Text = "PS2" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B36").Text
    End If



         If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("D3").Text = "PS3" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B37").Text
    End If

         If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("D3").Text = "PS4" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B38").Text
    End If

         If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("D3").Text = "PS5" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B39").Text
    End If

         If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("D3").Text = "PS6" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B40").Text
    End If

         If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("D3").Text = "PS7" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B41").Text
    End If

         If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("D3").Text = "PS8" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B42").Text
    End If





    'EXAM2'



        If LCase(Cells(i, "E").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "Educ" Then

        bodymessage1 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B7").Text
    End If


        If LCase(Cells(i, "E").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "A1" Then

        bodymessage1 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B26").Text
    End If


        If LCase(Cells(i, "E").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "A2" Then

        bodymessage1 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B27").Text
    End If


        If LCase(Cells(i, "E").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "A3" Then

        bodymessage1 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B28").Text
    End If


        If LCase(Cells(i, "E").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "A4" Then

        bodymessage1 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B29").Text
    End If


        If LCase(Cells(i, "E").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "A5" Then

        bodymessage1 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B30").Text
    End If


        If LCase(Cells(i, "E").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "A6" Then

        bodymessage1 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B31").Text
    End If
        If LCase(Cells(i, "E").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "A7" Then

        bodymessage1 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B32").Text
    End If
     If LCase(Cells(i, "E").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "A8" Then

        bodymessage1 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B33").Text
    End If






    'k'


        If LCase(Cells(i, "E").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "K1" Then

        bodymessage1 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B20").Text
    End If





     If LCase(Cells(i, "E").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "K2" Then

        bodymessage1 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B21").Text
    End If



    If LCase(Cells(i, "E").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "K3" Then

        bodymessage1 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B22").Text
    End If


    If LCase(Cells(i, "E").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "K4" Then

        bodymessage1 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B23").Text
    End If

    If LCase(Cells(i, "E").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "K5" Then

        bodymessage1 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B24").Text
    End If

    'ps1'


    If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "PS1" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B35").Text
    End If

    If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "PS2" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B36").Text
    End If

    If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "PS3" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B37").Text
    End If

    If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "PS4" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B38").Text
    End If

    If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "PS5" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B39").Text
    End If

    If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "PS6" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B40").Text
    End If

    If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "PS7" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B41").Text
    End If

    If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "PS8" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B42").Text
    End If





    'Exam3'



        If LCase(Cells(i, "F").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("F3").Text = "Educ" Then

        bodymessage2 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B7").Text
    End If


        If LCase(Cells(i, "F").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("F3").Text = "A1" Then

        bodymessage2 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B26").Text
    End If


        If LCase(Cells(i, "F").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("F2").Text = "A2" Then

        bodymessage2 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B27").Text
    End If


        If LCase(Cells(i, "F").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("F2").Text = "A3" Then

        bodymessage2 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B28").Text
    End If


        If LCase(Cells(i, "F").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("F2").Text = "A4" Then

        bodymessage2 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B29").Text
    End If


        If LCase(Cells(i, "F").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("F2").Text = "A5" Then

        bodymessage2 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B30").Text
    End If


        If LCase(Cells(i, "F").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("F2").Text = "A6" Then

        bodymessage2 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B31").Text
    End If

        If LCase(Cells(i, "F").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("F2").Text = "A7" Then

        bodymessage2 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B32").Text
    End If

     If LCase(Cells(i, "F").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("F2").Text = "A8" Then

        bodymessage2 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B33").Text
    End If





    'K'


        If LCase(Cells(i, "F").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("F3").Text = "K1" Then

        bodymessage2 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B20").Text
    End If

    If LCase(Cells(i, "F").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("F3").Text = "K2" Then

        bodymessage2 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B21").Text
    End If
    If LCase(Cells(i, "F").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("F3").Text = "K3" Then

        bodymessage2 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B22").Text
    End If

    If LCase(Cells(i, "F").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("F3").Text = "K4" Then

        bodymessage2 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B23").Text
    End If

    If LCase(Cells(i, "F").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("F3").Text = "K5" Then

        bodymessage2 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B24").Text
    End If

    'PS'


    If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "PS1" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B35").Text
    End If
    If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "PS2" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B36").Text
    End If
    If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "PS3" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B37").Text
    End If
    If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "PS4" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B38").Text
    End If
    If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "PS5" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B39").Text
    End If
    If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "PS6" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B40").Text
    End If
    If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "PS7" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B41").Text
    End If

    If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("E3").Text = "PS8" Then

        bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B42").Text
    End If




    'EXam'



        If LCase(Cells(i, "G").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("G3").Text = "Educ" Then

        bodymessage3 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B7").Text
    End If


        If LCase(Cells(i, "G").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("G3").Text = "A1" Then

        bodymessage3 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B26").Text
    End If


        If LCase(Cells(i, "G").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("G3").Text = "A2" Then

        bodymessage3 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B27").Text
    End If


        If LCase(Cells(i, "G").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("G3").Text = "A3" Then

        bodymessage3 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B28").Text
    End If


        If LCase(Cells(i, "G").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("G3").Text = "A4" Then

        bodymessage3 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B29").Text
    End If


        If LCase(Cells(i, "G").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("G3").Text = "A5" Then

        bodymessage3 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B30").Text
    End If


        If LCase(Cells(i, "G").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("G3").Text = "A6" Then

        bodymessage3 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B31").Text
    End If
        If LCase(Cells(i, "G").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("G3").Text = "A7" Then

        bodymessage3 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B32").Text
    End If

     If LCase(Cells(i, "G").Text) = "dnm" And Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("G3").Text = "A8" Then

        bodymessage3 = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B33").Text
End If
```

Comment: What's your question? Have you tried refactoring to shorten and/or reduce duplication?

Comment: I'm with jonrsharpe.  Loop through the rows or columns.  Put your checks and bodymessage building in the loop.  Is that what you are asking for? A way to make your code smaller.

Comment: Now your title is "Large procedure Error". What error are you getting?

Comment: Please give some comments to above code. What are you want?

Comment: @MatthewD. the error is "Procedure too large - Compile Error"

Comment: Riadh, see the answer that I posted. you may have to refresh the page to see it

Comment: Please explain your high level logic. Example:  I send an email, the body will be based on what is in cells A and D. The value is pulled from Sheet 2 Column A.

Comment: I'm sorry, the *what*?!  *"Candidate"*? At least misspell it consistently! If your code is too large to even fit in a question, it's no surprise that VBA doesn't like it. We aren't here to refactor that whole mess for you; long story short, *you need to learn to program*. Start by finding out what DRY means.

Answer (score 6):

Do this and everything will be fine.

1. Instead of having so many variables as shown below

   ```
   Dim bodymessage  As String
   Dim bodymessage1 As String
   Dim bodymessage2 As String
   Dim bodymessage3 As String
   Dim bodymessage4  As String
   Dim bodymessage5 As String
   Dim Bodymessage6 As String
   ```

   Use Arrays. For example

   ```
   Dim bodymessage(1 to 7) as String
   ```
2. Delete Unnecessary blank lines and delete unnecessary comments.
3. These 6 lines for example

   ```
   fr1 = ""
   fr2 = ""
   fr3 = ""
   fr4 = ""
   fr5 = ""
   fr6 = ""
   fr7 = ""
   fr8 = ""
   fr9 = ""
   ```

   can be written in 2 lines

   ```
   fr1 = "": fr2 = "": fr3 = "": fr4 = "": fr5 = ""
   fr6 = "": fr7 = "": fr8 = "": fr9 = ""
   ```

   This is just an example. In the above case I will do exactly what I mentioned in point 1. Use an Array.

   One more point. You do not need to clear each element of the array individually. You can use `Erase MyAr`. Here is an example

   ```
   Sub Sample()
       Dim MyAr(1 To 5)

       For i = 1 To 5
           MyAr(i) = 1
       Next i

       For i = 1 To 5
           Debug.Print MyAr(i)
       Next i

       Erase MyAr

       For i = 1 To 5
           Debug.Print MyAr(i) '<~~ Nothing there
       Next i

       Debug.Print UBound(MyAr)
   End Sub
   ```
4. You are repeating `If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm"`. Use it only once and put the rest of the if statements inside it and convert them to `Select Case`. For example

   ```
   If LCase(Cells(i, "D").Text) = "dnm" Then
       Select Case Sheets("Exams-email results").Range("D3").Text
       Case "Educ": bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B7").Text
       Case "A1": bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B26").Text
       Case "A2": bodymessage = vbNewLine & "    **    " & Sheets("SOMC-Legend").Range("B27").Text
       '
       '~~> And so on
       '
       End Select
   End If
   ```

If you apply all that I have mentioned above then your error will go away :) Always try to write clear and precise code :)

Comment: Big ups for the `Dim bodymessage(1 to 7)...`, I didn't realize you could do that. Nice!  For the `fr1 = ""` part, could you do a For loop? `for i = 1 to 9, fri = ""` (I notice you can't do that because it'll think `fri` is a variable, but is there a way to do like `fr[i]` ...?

Comment: @BruceWayne it would be the same format as the bodymessage array - fr(i) = the ith element of the fr group.

Comment: You can use a variable variable but that is too complex in this scenario and not needed. You can use array in the case of `fr`. so something like `Dim fri(1 to 9)` and store values in it like `fri(1) = "Blah Blah"` and to clear the array you do not have to do `fr(1)="": fr(2)=""` etc... You can simply clear it in one line using `Erase fr` @BruceWayne

Comment: ++good going... I would have gone one step further and put the "exams-email-results" and their corresponding "SOMC-Legend" range name in a 2-D array or something. That would further shrink all those `SELECT CASE` statements into one or two lines :)

Comment: Thanks @Grade'Eh'Bacon and Siddharth! I knew would be too complex for this, but your answer prompted that question, good to know!

Comment: @PradeepKumar: What the hell are you doing keeping awake at these unearthly hours :D Yes, that is also a good suggestion.